# Validation of complex nested objects in Django Rest Framework 3

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

**My situation:** The client needs to PUT a deep object graph to my Rest Framework 3-powered server, and there are lots of validation rules that need to be applied to the incoming data. For example, imagine incoming JSON like so (this is a contrived example):

```
{  // a sales order
    dateOrdered: '2015-02-04T13:23:00-800',
    customer: 5400,  // the customer ID
    items: [
        {
            sku: "TV100",  // the stock item ID
            quantity: 1,
        },
        {
            sku: "HDMI04",  // the stock item ID
            quantity: 3,
        }
    ]
}
```

And the following serializers:

```py
class OrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    dateOrdered = DateTimeField()
    customer = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Customer.objects.all())
    items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
    def validate(self, data):
        # see my question below

class OrderItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    sku = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Item.objects.all())
    quantity = IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
```

The `validate()` method will receive a Python `dict` that is a mix of `dict`s, `list`s, and Model objects, like so:

```py
data = {
    'dateOrdered':  datetime.datetime(...)
    'customer':  <Customer.object at 0x....>
    'items': [
        {
            'sku': <Item.object at 0x....>
            'quantity': 1,
        },
        {
            'sku': <Item.object at 0x....>
            'quantity': 3,
        }
    ]
}
```

**My problem:** validating this "mixed" data structure is ugly (especially in my actual application, where the data structure is much deeper and more complex). I and future maintainers need to remember which "nodes" are Model objects vs `dict`s; the `list`s and `dict`s have no business logic methods to help with the validation; etc.

It would be much nicer to get the "final" object graph of Django models and just call `clean()` on that -- doing so would allow me to implement my validation logic in the models themselves, taking advantage of the object graph, allowing reuse of the validation logic in other contexts, etc.

**My question:** does anyone have any experience with complex validation like this, and if so, do you have any advice or best practices you can share?

Thanks!

Comment: similar question over here with 3 distinct approaches discussed:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651167/nested-validation-in-django-rest-framework

Comment: and another very good one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324341/django-rest-framework-serialize-data-from-nested-json-fields-to-plain-object

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to create items in sub-serilizers:

```
class OrderItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    sku = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Item.objects.all())
    quantity = IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        item = OrderItem(sku=data['sku'], quantity=data['quantity'])
        item.clean()
        return {'item': item}
```

Then you will receive something like this:

```
data = {
    'dateOrdered':  datetime.datetime(...)
    'customer':  <Customer.object at 0x....>
    'items': [
        {
            'item': <OrderItem.object>
        },
        {
            'item': <OrderItem.object>
        }
    ]
}
```

Warning: new `OrderItemSerializer` is quite specific and can be used only as nested serializer.

Comment: Interesting, this is worth investigating. In the meantime... are you needlessly wrapping each `OrderItem` in a `dict`? I'd like `items` to be a list of `OrderItem` instances.

Comment: Actually not. You can return `OrderItem` object as internal value.