# Django rest framework nested serializer inside non-model serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a page where there are few separate serializers and they dont have relation. Instead of calling them one by one, I want to call all of them at once(only for listing, not for writing. dont worry about writing).

So want to create a single serializer with each of them inside them as fields(nested serializer).

Like this:

```
class MarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     # Shows list of marks
     class Meta:
         model = Mark
         fields = blah blah

class TopCricketerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Show list of top cricketers


and more..
```

Here is common serializer I am planning:

```
CommonSerializer(serializers.Serializer): # Correct me if am using wrong serializer of if no serializer needed 
    marks = MarkSerializer(many=True)
    top_cricketers = TopCricketerSerializer(many=True)
    # more such non-related fields
```

Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: I think the real question is how are you going to pass the data to the serializer!!

Comment: So, Is there some answer useful about that question?

Comment: @CarMoreno, i left an answer with an example. You can check it

Answer (score 0):

Your serializer looks fine for read-only operations. See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37396379/2532070) for more information.

To make this serializer writeable (if that's necessary) you would need to include `create` and/or `update` methods on your `CommonSerializer` as [in the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)

Comment: My question is for reading/loading only. Only to load all of them at once, dont worry about writing.

Answer (score 0):

You understand everything correctly. Here's an example of how it will look

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Mark, TopCricketer

class MarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Mark
        fields = "__all__"

class TopCricketerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Mark
        fields = "__all__"

class CommonSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    marks = MarkSerializer(many=True)
    top_cricketers = TopCricketerSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        marks = MarkSerializer(data=validated_data['marks'], many=True)
        marks.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        marks.save()

        top_cricketers = TopCricketerSerializer(data=validated_data['top_cricketers '], many=True)
        top_cricketers.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        top_cricketers.save()

        return self.__class__({'marks': marks, 'top_cricketers ': top_cricketers})

# views.py
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import CommonSerializer
from .models import Mark, TopCricketer


class CommonAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommonSerializer
    
    # retrieve
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        marks = Mark.objects.all()
        top_cricketers = TopCricketer.objects.all()
        serializer= self.get_serializer({'marks': marks, 'top_cricketers ': top_cricketers})
        return Response(serializer.data)
   
   # create
   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer= self.get_serializer(data = request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```